# IF(AND) Conditional formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am struggling to create a formula for a table with conditional formatting where I compare a cell in one column (Items) to another cell in a separate column (Need items 3 or higher). I don't want to highlight the entire row, but I do need to format the cell so it changes.

***Mock Image of what is needed:***
[image]

I'm currently trying to use `=OR($A$2:$A$78="Item 1",$A$2:$A$78="Item 2")`
What is wrong with the above condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In conditional formatting you no need to mention full range of cells. Rather use first cell. Excel will automatically check for other cells based on applied cells. Try this function in custom CF rule-

```
=OR($A2="Item 1",$A2="Item 2")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I see my error. I was selecting the entire column in the table instead of just the row i.e $A$2:$A$78 vs. $A$2. Because of my error I was highlighting EVERYTHING in the column I wanted instead of just select cells.